# NServiceBus ConfigureComponent is obsolete

Tags: nservicebus

Our code has a lot of the following:

```
EndpointConfig.cs: 
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<Foo>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<Bar>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None);
```

etc, which gives compiler warnings that the ConfigureComponent method is obsolete.

What is the non-obsolete way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace ComponentCallModelEnum with the appropriate DependencyLifecycle.X

Comment: Thanks. I mis-read the compiler warning. In Visual Studio it looks like the ConfigureComponent method is obsolete because it gets the blue squiggly underline. As you say, it's the ComponentCallModelEnum that is obsolete.